# Magento Sales (special price) CMS Page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, cms, sales

I've tried several tutorials found around Google... but none of those seems to work for me.

I need to create a Sales page, for products with special prices, that acts like a normal category page, with the pagination etc. The best way, I think, is to create it as a CMS so later I can have the url like this: **myshop.com/sales** . But I nothing is working.

can somebody give a hand of doing this, please!?

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a block that extends the product list block. Create it inside one of your extensions or create a separate extension. Let's assume the extension is called `Easylife_Special`.

You need to create this block:
`app/code/local/Easylife/Special/Block/Catalog/Product/Sales.php`

```
<?php 
class Easylife_Special_Block_Catalog_Product_Sales extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List{
    protected function _getProductCollection(){
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
                ->setTime('00:00:00')
                ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

            $todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
                ->setTime('23:59:59')
                ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
            $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());


            $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                    0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                ), 'left')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                ), 'left')
                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    array(
                        array('attribute' => 'special_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                        array('attribute' => 'special_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                        )
                  )
            ;
            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Now create a cms page named 'sales' (or whatever you want) with this content:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

and in the Layout Update XML put this:

```
<reference name="content">
                <block type="special/catalog_product_sales" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/> 
                </block>
          <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action> 
            </block>
</reference>
```

When you visit the page /sales you should see all the products with the special price filled and with the special price available today.

**[EDIT]**
modified my answer because I realized the page numbers don't appear.

Comment: hi, I've done as you said. but nothing is pulled out. div is empty

Comment: Check again because I edited the response. For me it worked perfectly. Make sure you clear the cache. Check the logs for errors. What do you see in the page?

Comment: tried with the updated code too.. I get the footer and the header. but the content is empty 
http://i.imgur.com/3ncYBUG.png

Comment: Check again the field 'Layout Update XML'. for some reason when I saved the page the first time it ended up empty.

Comment: checked code is at its place... :/

Comment: If there is no error in var/log I have no other idea why it doesn't work for your.

Comment: nope. no errors in var/log/system.log

Comment: Maybe you can try including the block in your cms page and leave the xml update. CMS page content should then be {{block type="special/catalog_product_sales" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" method="toHtml"}}. Make sure to input it in HTML view, not in WYSIWYG.

Comment: @ravipatel. Not sure what you mean

Comment: hii i want this code with full source like extension module compatible to  magento1.9.0.1.

Comment: @ravipatel. Sorry, I don't have it anymore. But the main things are in the answer. You only need to add the declaration file in `app/etc/modules`, and the `config.xml` where you declare the block alias `<blocks><special><class>Easylife_Special_Block</class></special></blocks>`

Comment: Thanks for reply. My code is hear please check one time. https://github.com/rvpatel/Magento-Special-Product-Module

Comment: hiii Please one time review my code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your module's config.xml in etc folder. Now check whether you have included the block like this :

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <prolist>
            <class>Browsewire_Prolist_Block</class>
        </prolist>
    </blocks>
  </global>
```

Now if you have done this, you can get the marius's solution working.
Also make sure about the structure of your whole module.